# How do I sum and label the total of "Confirmed" Cases per x-axis "Date"

Tags: ggplot2, label, summarize, geom-col

I want to label the sum of the column of "Confirmed" Cases for each "Date"

```
ggplot(filter(COVID1, COUNTY %in% c("Kent")))+
geom_col(aes(x = Date, y = Cases, fill = CASE_STATUS), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), width = .88)+
```

[image]

dp(COUNTY       Date CASE_STATUS Cases Deaths Cases.Cumulative Deaths.Cumulative             Updated
1     Kent 2020-03-01   Confirmed     1      0                1                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31

With this code, I get this result, which is half the value expected.

```
geom_text(aes(x = Date, y = Cases, label = stat(y), group = Date), stat = 'summary')+
```

[image]

```
 filter(COVID1, COUNTY %in% c("Kent"))
```

COUNTY       Date CASE_STATUS Cases Deaths Cases.Cumulative Deaths.Cumulative             Updated
1     Kent 2020-03-01   Confirmed     1      0                1                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
2     Kent 2020-03-02   Confirmed     1      0                2                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
3     Kent 2020-03-03   Confirmed     0      0                2                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
4     Kent 2020-03-04   Confirmed     3      0                5                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
5     Kent 2020-03-05   Confirmed     0      0                5                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
6     Kent 2020-03-06   Confirmed     1      0                6                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
7     Kent 2020-03-07   Confirmed     2      0                8                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
8     Kent 2020-03-08   Confirmed     1      0                9                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31
9     Kent 2020-03-09   Confirmed     2      0               11                 0 2020/07/06 12:46:31

Comment: Please `dput()` your data `COVID1` in order to help you!

Comment: Sorry, too new at this, don't exactly know how to do this.

Comment: Just go to `R` console type `dput(COVID1)` which is your main dataframe. Copy the results. Edit the question. Paste what you copied from console.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried, it's not exactly what I wanted but close.

```
geom_text(aes(x = Date, y = Cases, label = stat(2*y), group = Date), stat = 'summary', postion = position_dodge(.9), vjust = .4, angle = 90, color = "white")+
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this only works with one set of data filter not with multiple. For example, it does not work with filter(COVID1, COUNTY %in% c("Kent, x, y, z"))

Comment: `c("Kent, x, y, z")` should be `c("Kent", "x", "y", "z")`

Comment: I could send complete source code, and link to data if anyone is interested.

Comment: Very interesting. The label works when I use this formula: label =  stat(2*c*y), where c is the number of counties inside c("Kent", "x", "Y"). In this case stat(2*3*y). How to put that in code, or better way?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, this does not exactly work either.

Comment: Hi John. You don't need to send full data or script, however, if you could try to boil it down to a *minimal* reproducible example. There is basically hardly any problem that cannot be boiled down to using one of the inbuilt data sets. Often, when trying to reproduce your problem on other data / artificial data, you get to the core of the problem all by yourself.

Comment: I am re-posting this soon, with minimized data, because it could be too cumbersome to follow